# Use package.json data in HTML ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a scenario where I want to use `name` from `package.json` in my HTML so that I can use it as the title of the document.

I know it can be done using `react-helmet` but the organization doesn't allow to install that package. Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can import package.json file directly in your js or jsx file.

```
import packageJson from '<root-path-of-project->/package.json';

const { name } = packageJson;
```

Comment: It will be in jsx or js file right. I want the variables in the HTML file as `title` and other things will be set only in `index.html` file right.

Comment: Set the title using Javascript once you get it from the JSON - `document.title = name`

Comment: if you are not using SSR, then your options are update title in index.html during build  else use `document.title`

Comment: But setting `description` and similar elements will be difficult which essentially needs to be set in meta tags.

Comment: If you are using webpack then checkout https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options, you can import packageJson in webpack file and inject your meta during build time.